# Subtracting finite rings in Assembly

Tags: assembly, modular-arithmetic

For the finite ring R<sub>2</sub> = {00000000,00000001..,11111111} find:

11010111 - 10101010 = N<sub>2</sub> = ___________.

I am trying to answer this question. I cannot subtract normally in assembly so, using the formula, i get:

```
(11010111 + ~10101010) mod (1000000) = ?
```

which i believe equates to:

```
100101101 mod 1000000 = ?
```

I am now stuck on solving this part. Can anyone help me solve this or if familiar with this type of question, let me know if i am doing it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just everyday 8 bit arithmetic, isn't it? Also your `mod` has two zeroes less than it should. The result is simply the low 8 bits, so `00101101`.

Comment: Thanks I was doing something wrong with mod I get it now! Does it look like I did the additive inverse of ~10101010 correctly?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.